# Colocar upload de imagem blogger

Tags: html, file-upload, blogger

Tem como colocar uma caixa para upload de imagem no blogger que vá direto para meu e-mail? Precisaria receber algumas imagens de comprovante de deposito.

Answer (score 1):

Não, o blogger não é uma plataforma muito customizável. Tente usar [WordPress](http://wordpress.com).